# listView recycles view when scrolling

Tags: android

I am changing the background color of a rowView inside my CustomAdapter, when I scroll down the list and back up the view gets refreshed and the background disappears, I know it is because the listView recycling mechanism but I can't make it stop.

Here's my getView function:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Holder holder = new Holder();
        final View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
        holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (position != 0)
                    rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(70, 190, 200));
          }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
```

What I wanted to do is: store inside an array all the position already been pressed and then color everyone of them every time. I saw a lot of other solution but I don't fully understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a different approach and store somewhere the position of the item you have clicked on. Then when you create the View check if the position is stored and change the background.
Hope it helps you

Comment: Good approach. Thanks :) I just had problems.

Answer (score 0):

make a  boolean array instead and set true for every item you click.

```
boolean[] isSelected;
```

then in your getView method code something like this.

```
rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (position != 0){
                rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(70, 190, 200)); 
                isselected[position] = true;             }
             }
    });
if(isSelected[position]){
     rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(70, 190, 200)); 
}
```

Comment: I think you must set the Boolean array length at the beginning so a Set will be better.